# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: / NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have a fresh installation of laravel 5.3,I am getting this error everytime i use a route.
"NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161" in ......

I used php artisan make:auth and created logins and register.But still didn't work (in laravel 5.3).

After that I  updated xampp to the latest version and also installed laravel 5.4,
Now i am getting the same error message with a different line,"179"

Here is my route file

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
 });

 Route::get('/chat', function () {
return view('chat');
  });
```

I have a view in view/chat.blade.php

```
 --------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | chat     |      | Closure | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

I maybe missing something.
can someone please explain,Thank You

Comment: whats the url that giving you error??

Comment: Check your .htaccess file and add rewrite rule. follow this link if you are a linux user https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: first php artisan route:clear then add Auth::routes(); to your web.php

Comment: Tried route:clear then add Auth::routes();  already Nothing works !

Comment: @Sohel0415 /chat

Answer (score 0):

Clear route cache

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Then you can chack your routes by

```
php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 0):

For active login/register, You need to add auth routes to your routes/web.php

```
Auth::routes();
```